# Java - how to reduce iteration loops for enemies

Tags: java, game-loop

I have many places in my code where I'm iterating through the enemies array and it seems to me it could be optimised somehow, but I can't see how it can be done. For example these two loop checks:

```
private void arc1() {
    for (Enemy e : gs.getEnemies())
        if (e.distanceFromPlayer() < 32 && !e.seen) {
            arc1.setActive(true);
            return;
        }
    arc1.setActive(false);
}

private void arc2() {
    for (Enemy e : gs.getEnemies())
        if (e.distanceFromPlayer() < 24) {
            arc2.setActive(true);
            return;
        }
    arc2.setActive(false);
}
```

They're both just checking the distance from the player with one having an extra condition and a different distance. Is there a way to combine them into one? I tried doing it but it didn't work correctly.

Will it actually give any benefit performance wise to combine into one in any case? It does look like duplicate code but not sure if there would actually be any performance benefit.

Comment: What is arc1 and arc2, mainly .setActive on it. Since it doesnt sem to be from the loop of enemies you are iterating.

Comment: @Zibelas They're the function names, why? You can call them anything it doesn't matter, they just set something active or inactive based on distance. They're something on the player, you are correct, not on the enemies themselves.

Comment: It makes a difference in the effect. For example you can't combine the loop if arc1 and arc2 change different behavior. If arc2 gets to true, based on the snipped arc1 is most likely true as well but not in the case it is not seen. Since you exit the loop on first confirmed setting true, there can be some enemies that are later setting arc1 true but would be false when you exit on arc2. Just based on what you posted you would need to modify the exit condition to not interupt the loop.

Comment: @Zibelas OK I see what you mean. They are two entirely separate things that are active or inactive independently. As it is arc2 would exit prematurely, but both functions are running continuously, both looping through all enemies, so would I be correct to assume that arc2 exiting prematurely gives no performance benefit? So I may as well have them as one?

Comment: I would say it depends on your amount of enemies that you need to loop through. If the behavior is really a lot different, it makes more sense to leave them separately. You can combine the loop with extra checks to handle the prematurely exit as well. You might save one extra loop in the best case. Just it will be hard to read once you reach arc25 and you might consider a different system at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just about combining the code, something like this should have the same result with only one loop.

```
private void combinedArc() {
    arc1.setActive(false);
    arc2.setActive(false);
    for (Enemy e : gs.getEnemies()) {
        float distanceFromPlayer = e.distanceFromPlayer();
        if (!arc1.isActive() && distanceFromPlayer < 32 && !e.seen) {
            arc1.setActive(true);
        }
        if (!arc2.isActive() && distanceFromPlayer < 24) {
            arc2.setActive(true);
        }
        if (arc1.isActive() && arc2.isActive()) {
            return;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Ok and will there be a performance benefit (however small is unimportant) in having this in one loop only?

Comment: The biggest benefit would be that since it is combined, now you can extract e.distanceFromPlayer() as a variable and do not need to do the math twice. The saved loop is small benefit, doing the math once it a bigger one, assuming you do some calculation in e.distanceFromPlayer()

Comment: Putting the `setActive(false)` at the top made my own attempt at the combined function work too. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

These two examples in particular seem to search for entities in a given area. Queries like that can often be sped up considerably by storing entities (or at least references to them) in a data-structure optimized for spacial queries.

Two common options are various variants of spacial trees or spatial hashing.

Example of options for spacial trees are [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). What most trees have in common is that it is pretty quick to get all entities within an given rectangular area, but it's usually a rather expensive operation to move entities, because doing so can require to recalculate large sections of the tree. That makes them most useful for immobile entities.

Spatial hashing means that you divide your game world into a grid of rectangular sections and then have a list for every section with the entities which are currently in that section. You store those sections in a 2-dimensional array, so acquiring a section by coordinates is a very fast operation. When you want to check against all entities around the player, you only need to iterate the lists of the section the player is in and adjacent sections.

Comment: Ok that's interesting, I didn't know about those.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my own previous attempt at this combined function to work by moving the `setActive(false)` to the top as in the answer from Zibelas, so just for completeness,  am adding it as an alternative answer too.

```
private void combinedArc() {
    arc1.setActive(false);
    arc2.setActive(false);
    for (Enemy e : gs.getEnemies()) {
        float distanceFromPlayer = e.distanceFromPlayer();
        if (distanceFromPlayer < 24)
            arc2.setActive(true);
        if (distanceFromPlayer < 32 && !e.seen) {
            arc1.setActive(true);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zibelas Yeah you're right, too many brackets. I've edited it now.

Comment: There is still the problem of return, imagine you have 3 enemies in your list in this order: distance 40, distance 28, distance 20. Your old code would set arc1 and arc2 true, your new code only arc1. You can only exit prematurely the loop if both arc1 and arc2 are true.

Comment: True there would be some circumstances where it wouldn't work. It's a pity the further distance has a second condition otherwise it would all be much simpler.

Comment: The code I posted in my answer is handling those situations. You still can exit prematurely but it is not producing "some circumstances where it wouldn't work" which are usually called bugs.